# Storing data and retrieving it in gremlin java while traversing the graph

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I need to traverse a path and the selection of particular path will be done on basis of the data in some intermediate vertex of the path.

I have come across store() function in GremlinPipeLine to store data in list or data can be stored in map using groupBy function.But my question is how to use the stored data in the later part of traversal where the exact path needs to find out based on this data.

**A - > B -> C-> D ->E**

```
                  *-> F -> G ->I -> J*

                   *-> L -> M-> N -> O*
```

In the above example node B has a property (Route), similarly Node F and L has property (Route) so when the traverser is at node E the next node is decided based on the property(Route) of node B i.e. the one (F or L) having the same route number is selected.

So how do we do this using GremlinPipeLine.

Have tried using fixed "Route" at Point E using filter and PipeLineFunction, But was not able to use the 'Route' value of B at E.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response Using GremlinPipeline :

```
public Graph createGraph()
{
    Graph g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph();
    String [] ids ={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","L","M","N","O"};
    int i= 0;
    for (String s:ids)
    {
        Vertex v = g.addVertex(s);
        i++;
        v.setProperty("route",i);
    }
    g.getVertex("L").setProperty("route",2); // If you want "F" as the next vertex from E then mark the route of "F" as 2.
    g.addEdge(1,g.getVertex("A"),g.getVertex("B"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(2,g.getVertex("B"),g.getVertex("C"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(3,g.getVertex("C"),g.getVertex("D"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(4,g.getVertex("D"),g.getVertex("E"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(5,g.getVertex("E"),g.getVertex("F"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(6,g.getVertex("F"),g.getVertex("G"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(17,g.getVertex("G"),g.getVertex("I"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(18,g.getVertex("I"),g.getVertex("J"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(19,g.getVertex("E"),g.getVertex("L"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(20,g.getVertex("L"),g.getVertex("M"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(21,g.getVertex("M"),g.getVertex("N"),"x") ;
    g.addEdge(22,g.getVertex("N"),g.getVertex("O"),"x") ;

    return  g;
}

public void traverse(Graph graph)
{
    final Map<String,Object> cache = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    final String attribute="route";
    GremlinPipeline pipes = new GremlinPipeline(graph.getVertex("A")).out().sideEffect(new PipeFunction<Vertex,Vertex>() {

        public Vertex compute(Vertex vertex)
        {
            cache.put(attribute,vertex.<Object>getProperty(attribute));
            return vertex;
        }
    }).out().out().out().out().filter(new PipeFunction<Vertex,Boolean>() {
        public Boolean compute(Vertex vertex)
        {
            if (vertex.getProperty(attribute) == cache.get(attribute))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }).out().out().out().path();

    while(pipes.hasNext())
    {
        ArrayList<Vertex> vertices = (ArrayList<Vertex>)pipes.next();
        for (Vertex v : vertices)
        {
            System.out.print("->"+v.getId());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not totally clear to me. Maybe you can include a small sample graph. However maybe the following helps:

```
route = null; g.v('A').out.sideEffect{route = it.route}.out.out.out.out.filter{it.route == route}.out.out.out
```

The idea is that you simply `filter` out the branches of the traversal that do not  agree to the `route` property of the first neighbor of `A` which is `B`. Keep in mind that `route` will be assigned multiple times if `A` has more than one neighbor.

With the following example

```
g = new TinkerGraph()

ids = ['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
ids.each{g.addVertex(it)}

g.addEdge(g.v('A'), g.v('B'), 'x')
g.addEdge(g.v('B'), g.v('C'), 'x')
g.addEdge(g.v('C'), g.v('D'), 'x')
g.addEdge(g.v('D'), g.v('E'), 'x')

g.addEdge(g.v('E'), g.v('F'), 'x')
g.addEdge(g.v('F'), g.v('G'), 'x')
g.addEdge(g.v('G'), g.v('I'), 'x')
g.addEdge(g.v('I'), g.v('J'), 'x')

g.addEdge(g.v('E'), g.v('L'), 'x')
g.addEdge(g.v('L'), g.v('M'), 'x')
g.addEdge(g.v('M'), g.v('N'), 'x')
g.addEdge(g.v('N'), g.v('O'), 'x')

g.v('B').route = 1
g.v('F').route = 0
g.v('L').route = 1
```

I get `v[O]`

Comment: Thanks Faber... You got it correct... that helped me a lot...Will Edit your response in Java as well, as there is a lack of Gremlin Java example .. might help someone ..

Comment: I propose that you add the Java pipes example in a separate answer. I don't want to accept your additions because I don't know if they are correct. Don't know much about pipes. … and don't forget to accept my answer ;)